# Which register does BR check in LC-3

Tags: branch, lc3

The title pretty much explains it. I think BR checks the last register that was modified but I just wanted to make sure. For example, here's some code that will shift the bits in R3 4 bits to the left.

`1. .ORIG x3000
2. AND R2, R2, #0
3. ADD R2, R2, #4
4. LOOP BRz DONE
5. ADD R2, R2, #-1
6. ADD R3, R3, R3
7. BR LOOP
8. DONE HALT
9. .END`

This would produce an infinite loop and I think the correct code should should invert lines 5 and 6. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BR checks the condition code register.

The condition code register is modified on any instruction that directly writes to a register.

In LC-3 these instructions would be ADD, AND, NOT, LEA, LD, LDR, and LDI

And yes lines 5 and 6 should be swapped.